# tvos UICollectionView lose focus to previous Focus Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tvos, uicollectionviewdelegate

I am building a `tvos` application. i have a strange bug where `UICollectionView` lose focus of the previously selected cell when i navigate back to that particular view. The scenario is some thing this like this.

I have two `UIViewControllers` `A` and `B`. `A` has a `UITableView` and it has three prototype cells in it. Each cell has a horizontal scrolling `UICollectionView` inside it. When i click on any of `UICollectionViewCell` it navigates to the `B` (detail page). I am presenting `B` modally.

Now when i press Menu button on Siri remote view `A` appears again (in other words view `B` is removed from View hierarchy) but the current selected cell is different then the previously selected. I have tried to use `remembersLastFocusedIndexPath` with both `true` and `false` values and also tried by implementing

`func indexPathForPreferredFocusedViewInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> NSIndexPath?`

but the control neves comes to this function when i navigate back to view A. I am also reloading every thing in `viewWillAppear` function.

Can any one help me in this. Thanks

Comment: Why are you reloading everything when A (re)appears?

Comment: Did this issue resolved @Madu

Comment: @Madu I am also facing the same issue. Did you find solution for it.

Answer (score 3):

The property **remembersLastFocusedIndexPath** should be set to **true** for the collectionView and **false** for the tableView.

Also, Are you reloading the UITableView in viewWillAppear i.e Is the table data being refreshed when the B is popped and A appears?
If Yes, then lastFocusedIndexPath will be nil on reload.

We faced the same issue. We solved it by not reloading the contents when B is popped.

*Maintain a flag say didPush. Set this flag to true when B is pushed. When A appears check whether the flag is set and only then fetch data and reload table.*

This worked for us.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember exactly, but I know there was a known issue for `remembersLastFocusedIndexPath` where it wasn't working as intended.

This is one workaround, although take it with a grand of salt as it does seem slightly *hacky* and it uses the common (but potentially unstable) approach of overriding the `preferredFocusedView` property.

```
private var viewToFocus: UIView?

override var preferredFocusView: UIView? {
    get {
        return self.viewToFocus
        }
    }
```

Save locally the indexPath of the *last* cell in `View A` when presenting `View B`

```
// [1] Saving and scrolling to the correct indexPath:

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    ...
    collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath:, atScrollPosition:, animated:)
    }

// [2] Create a dispatchTime using GCD before setting the cell at indexPath as the preferredFocusView:

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    ...
    let dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(CGFloat.min * CGFloat(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.viewToFocus = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath:)

        // [3] Request an update
        self.setNeedsFocusUpdate()

        // [4] Force a focus update
        self.updateFocusIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

The reason we split the two methods into both `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` is that it eliminates a bit of the animation jump. If anyone else could jump in with suggestions to improve or even alternate solutions, I'd also be interested!

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift**

If you want to focus collection view Cell then 
You can use collectionview Delegate method, method name is

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) 
{
}
```

You can use this method like this...

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

if let previousIndexPath = context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath,
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(previousIndexPath) {
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    cell.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
    cell.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
}

if let indexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath,
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 8.0
    cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    cell.contentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    cell.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
    cell.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9
    cell.contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: [.CenteredHorizontally, .CenteredVertically], animated: true)
}
}
```

Comment: I am using the above code but, when I reload I can find more than one cell is focussed. Can you please help?